# Split files using tar, gz, zip, or bzip2

Tags: linux, bash, file-io, compression

I need to compress a large file of about 17-20 GB. I need to split it into several files of around 1 GB per file.

I searched for a solution via Google and found ways using the [split](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_(Unix)) and [cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)) commands. But they did not work for large files at all. Also, they won't work in Windows; I need to extract it on a Windows machine.

Comment: I feel your pain but this doesn't seem to be programming related.

Comment: Many compression programs (e.g. like 7-Zip) is able to split the compressed file into volumes of a specified size for easier distribution.

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com, but the private beta doesn't start until tomorrow, I'm told.

Comment: May I ask why you need that file compressed?

Comment: If one of the two viable solutions posted here doesn't pan out, he'll be needing a programming solution.

Comment: The approved answer to this question, shows how you can do this using Python and the subprocess module: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368818/any-way-to-execute-a-piped-command-in-python-using-subprocess-module-without-usi
(Python is a scripting language available for Windows, so there is a chance this might work...)

Comment: Can we move this question to superuser forum if it's not applicable to programming? Because it's still applicable.

Answer (score 266):

You can use the [`split`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html) command with the `-b` option:

```
split -b 1024m file.tar.gz
```

It can be reassembled on a Windows machine using [Joshua's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120095/split-files-using-tar-gz-zip-or-bzip2/1120121#1120121).

```
copy /b file1 + file2 + file3 + file4 filetogether
```

---

As @Charlie stated in the comment below, you might want to set a prefix explicitly because it will use `x` otherwise, which can be confusing.

```
split -b 1024m "file.tar.gz" "file.tar.gz.part-"

// Creates files: file.tar.gz.part-aa, file.tar.gz.part-ab, file.tar.gz.part-ac, ...
```

---

The most effective solution is very close to the content of this answer:

```
# Create archives
tar cz my_large_file_1 my_large_file_2 | split -b 1024MiB - myfiles_split.tgz_

# Uncompress
cat myfiles_split.tgz_* | tar xz
```

This solution avoids the need to use an intermediate large file when (de)compressing. Use the tar -C option to use a different directory for the resulting files. btw if the archive consists from only a single file, tar could be avoided and only gzip used:

```
# Create archives
gzip -c my_large_file | split -b 1024MiB - myfile_split.gz_

# Uncompress
cat myfile_split.gz_* | gunzip -c > my_large_file
```

For Windows you can download ported versions of the same commands or use Cygwin.

Comment: if you don't add a prefix as the last argument after the filename to split you get output in files named xaa, xab, xac, xad....

Comment: Actually using `-b 1024MiB` gave an error that it was an invalid number of bytes. Using `--bytes=1024m` works.

Comment: And you don't have to use `cat` to reassemble the file. You can use `copy /b file1 + file2 + etc..` on Windows, then copy back to Linux and tar can read the reassembled tarball. I just tried it.

Comment: Split has the option `--numeric-suffixes`: use numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic.

Comment: If you prefer the prefix consisting of the original to avoid prefix name guessing using bash variables, use: `file=myfile.tar.gz` followed by `split -b 1024m $file ${file}-part-`. Re-assembly using  `cat ${file}-part-* > $file`

Comment: It's good idea to use `--verbose` option when splitting large files.

Answer (score 29):

If you are splitting from Linux, you can still reassemble in Windows.

```
copy /b file1 + file2 + file3 + file4 filetogether
```

Comment: You can also use `copy /b file* filetogether` -- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/71161

Comment: That works correctly only on NTFS and if the files are in NTFS sort order already. Try it on FAT or FAT32 = boom.

Comment: +1 make sure files are in right order!

Comment: @Joshua To be fair, if they're not, you've done a poor job naming.

Comment: @jpmc26: You know about FAT32's bad directory reordering habits right?

Answer (score 10):

Use [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29) to [split into multiple archives](http://web.archive.org/web/20130523111545/http://paulbradley.tv/44/).

There are plenty of programs that will work with tar files on Windows, including [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin).

Answer (score 9):

Tested code, initially creates a single archive file, then splits it:

```
 gzip -c file.orig > file.gz
 CHUNKSIZE=1073741824
 PARTCNT=$[$(stat -c%s file.gz) / $CHUNKSIZE]

 # the remainder is taken care of, for example for
 # 1 GiB + 1 bytes PARTCNT is 1 and seq 0 $PARTCNT covers
 # all of file
 for n in `seq 0 $PARTCNT`
 do
       dd if=file.gz of=part.$n bs=$CHUNKSIZE skip=$n count=1
 done
```

This variant omits creating a single archive file and goes straight to creating parts:

```
gzip -c file.orig |
    ( CHUNKSIZE=1073741824;
        i=0;
        while true; do
            i=$[i+1];
            head -c "$CHUNKSIZE" > "part.$i";
            [ "$CHUNKSIZE" -eq $(stat -c%s "part.$i") ] || break;
        done; )
```

In this variant, if the archive's file size is divisible by `$CHUNKSIZE`, then the last partial file will have file size 0 bytes.

Comment: That's what `split` does already.

Comment: ephemient Hey, i've dig some post looking just FOR THAT. I have no split nor zip commands/binaries on a certain device, and this one has worked perfectly. I'll prepare this code to work as split command :). Thank you much @Adrian Panasiuk. That's pefect for me.

Comment: But, i've tested and the result was a full file, not split. How can it be? Was a big file on a small device, so was a long process. Please test your solutions while posting :(

Comment: @erm3nda You never told us you need to avoid creating a temporary file! Please see second variant!

Comment: I was wrong about the 1º script, works perfect, was my mistake about the CHUNKSIZE variable.

There's NO reason to create a gzip intermediate file. You can run all in just one command with a pipe.

Both examples works, one does with dd and the other uses head data wrapper.

My main problem was the missing split/zip binaries and those both solutions are what i ask for when go inside that. Thx again.

Comment: I solved my problem yesterday using 7zip with `-v200m` option. But later i go back and test yours too and see my mistake :D

Comment: thanks, the split command was resulting in a full file with no split for me too, while your script worked. Note: if on a MacOS then substitute "stat -c%s" with "stat -f%z"

Comment: Thank you!  I just used something half way between your first and second example to make something that would take a gzip compressed file, stream it through the subshell, and make it into gzipped part files  - I couldn't find anything else that would work the same way.. I precalculated the number of parts (like the first example) but used the subshell to work on a single gunzippped stream.