# Any way to execute a piped command in Python using subprocess module, without using shell=True?

Tags: python, bash

I want to run a piped command line linux/bash command from Python, which first tars files, and then splits the tar file. The command would look like something this in bash:

```
> tar -cvf - path_to_archive/* | split -b 20m -d -a 5 - "archive.tar.split"
```

I know that I could execute it using subprocess, by settings shell=True, and submitting the whole command as a string, like so:

```
import subprocess    

subprocess.call("tar -cvf - path_to_archive/* | split -b 20m -d -a 5 - 'archive.tar.split'", shell=True)
```

...but for security reasons I would like to find a way to skip the "shell=True" part, (which takes a list of strings rather than a full command line string, and which can not handle the pipe char correctly). Is there any solution for this in Python? I.e., is it possible to set up linked pipes somehow, or some other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tar can split itself:

```
tar -L 1000000 -F name-script.sh cf split.tar largefile1 largefile2 ...
```

### name-script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "${TAR_ARCHIVE/_part*.tar/}"_part"${TAR_VOLUME}".tar >&"${TAR_FD}"
```

### To re-assemble

```
tar -M -F name-script.sh cf split.tar
```

Add this to your python program.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to avoid using shell=True, you can manually use [subprocess pipes](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline).

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p1 = Popen(["tar", "-cvf", "-", "path_to_archive"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["split", "-b", "20m", "-d", "-a", "5", "-", "'archive.tar.split'"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Note that if you do not use the shell, you will not have access to expansion of globbing characters like *. Instead you can use the `glob` module.

Comment: You could pass your argument through glob.glob() first, if you still want to support globbing.

Comment: True, I'll try to get around using globbing at all somehow, for better security, but thanks for the hint anyway.

Comment: @amertune Good call. Added to the answer.

Comment: wow, so cumbersome to use piped commands. I had expected python users would complain.

Comment: If the shell seems to wait for user input via keyboard, be sure not to forget "stdin=p1.stdout" as the second parameter of the second Popen. I forgot it and wondered.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you can't use tarfile? | http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html

```
import tarfile
tar = tarfile.open("sample.tar.gz")
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

Just write like a file like object using tarfile rather than invoking subprocess.

Comment: Problem is that I want to split the tarfile at the same time as I create it. I will create rather big files (~20Gb), in big numbers, so I prefer not to write to disk more than once, to make the script faster.

Comment: If ya say so but I still believe this problem would be better handled with tarfile

Comment: Yeah, true in general I suppose. Also, if there is a way to use tarfile piped together with the split operation, it would be interesting for me too...

Comment: Im sure you could split the tar with tarfile? Have you read the lib page?

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug, I wrote a subprocess wrapper for easier command piping in python:
https://github.com/houqp/shell.py

Example:

```
shell.ex("tar -cvf - path_to_archive") | "split -b 20m -d -a 5 - 'archive.tar.split'"
```