# Can I split compressed sql file using split linux command? If not, then any other method to do?

Tags: mysql, linux, bzip2, bigdata, database

I have a 30 GB compressed sql file (with extension .sql.bz2) and if I unzip it will become 300 GB. However due to disk space issue, I can't do the same.

Could I split the compressed sql file something like using split linux command? 
I tried but with no success. Any other approach?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look at this question: [split-files-using-tar-gz-zip-or-bzip2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120095/split-files-using-tar-gz-zip-or-bzip2)
I assume the reason you want to split it is to move it? And that you know you probably wont be able to import a small slice of the file into a database?