# How can I split a large tar.gz file into smaller tar.gz files of maximum 1 GB?

Tags: python, bash, split, tar, archive

I have a file `archive.tar.gz`, which is 38 GB in size. I want to store it in chunks of maximum 1 GB.

To do that, I would like to split it into sub-files `archive_0.tar.gz`, `archive_1.tar.gz`, ... so that each sub-file is individually readable (and not just the original file cut at the 1024-th byte).

In other words, each `archive_x.tar.gz` file should be a valid `tar.gz` file.

How can I do this? Preferably using shell scripting, or Python.

Comment: Do you have enough disk space for twice the data (uncompressed) on Linux?

Comment: Yes, there is plenty of space, it's not an issue

Comment: Please improve your question, do not comment it

Comment: Looks like this tool (googled for "split tar by size") might do the job: https://github.com/dmuth/tarsplit

Comment: Consider also, if allowed, using [afio](https://github.com/kholtman/afio) for backup on Linux

Comment: How is this not a duplicate? Or off-topic?

Comment: A lead: *[Split files using tar, gz, zip, or bzip2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120095/)* (2009. Closed as off-topic.)

Comment: Why must each sub-file be individually readable? Isn't some information ending up in the two different sub-files?

Comment: Re Windows: Cross-site duplicate: *[How can I split a large file on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/94083)*

Comment: Site [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) happily accepts such work orders. The solution will be provided in multiple scripting languages.

Answer (score -2):

Assume you have enough disk space, run Linux, and could have root permission:

1. List the files in the original *tar* archive, both with size and without

   ```
   tar tzvf archive.tar.gz > /tmp/archive-full-list
   tar tzf archive.tar.gz > /tmp/archive-list
   ```
2. write your [GNU AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) or Python script (or a C program using [libtar](https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Libtar)) parsing these archive lists, checking that no single file has 1 GB (uncompressed) data. Maybe use some [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/) or [Redis](https://redis.io/) or [PostgreSQL](https://postgresql.org) database to store the metadata, name (i.e., file path), permissions, owner and size of each file.
3. write another script chunking the data in single gigabyte uncompressed chunks, collecting file paths appropriately
4. run the appropriate *tar* commands, creating the `archive_x.tar.gz`

NB. The obtained "splitting" is probably not the optimal one (since *some* textual files of 2Gbytes might be compressed in less than one Gbyte; this is difficult to predict).